# Запрос на увеличение значения в поле от заданного числа

Tags: sql, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток. У меня имеется таблица пользователей с полями:

```
   id             
+-------------+
   percent    
+-------------+
   sum         
+-------------+
   filter
```

Мне нужно для каждого пользователя с filter=1 увеличить значение в поле sum на процент (из поля percent) от заданого числа. То есть если заданное число = 100 (может изменяться), то пользователю с percent=15 нужно увеличить значение поля sum на 15 (15 процентов от 100).

Все, что я сейчас могу, - сделать выборку всех пользователей с filter=1, а потом в цикле при помощи языка программирования считать для каждого пользователя процент и делать запрос в бд на установку нового значения поля sum... Мне кажется, что это не лучшее решение и поставленную задачу можно сделать при помощи sql.

Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь подскажет, в какую сторону смотреть или приведет пример sql запроса для заданной таблицы.

Comment: А вам потом не нужно менять значение filter?

Comment: Нет, filter неизменен.

Comment: @zidim, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `sum`=`sum`*(1+percent/100)
WHERE filter=1
```

Comment: Так у меня даже на калькуляторе не сходится, а попытки модифицировать это под себя приводят к ошибкам. У меня у каждого пользователя свой percent и свой sum. Получается, мне нужно узнать, сколько единиц составляет percent пользователя от заданного числа (в примере 100) и добавить к значению sum именно эти единицы. Документацию читал, сам подправить в консоли пробовал. Подправьте, пожалуйста, кто понимает, как это делается.

Comment: процент берется от поля sum или откуда?

Comment: @Ale_x,  
`Мне нужно для каждого пользователя с filter=1 увеличить значение в поле sum на процент (из поля percent) от заданого числа. То есть, если заданное число = 100 (может изменяться), то пользователю с percent=15 нужно увеличить значение поля sum на 15 (15 процентов от 100).`

Comment: я бы русский стал учить, пусть меня научат))) Зачем вопрос, который вы технически не можете сформулировать, еще нагромождать сложными и длинными предложениями((

'если заданное число = 100 (может изменяться)' - вот тут пусть автор поподробнее объяснит, что означает меняться. Для каждой строки свое число? Или сейчас выполнили запрос с числом 100, а после завтра с числом 200?

Comment: сегодня с числом 100, а через минуту с числом 200 - оно передается бэкенду от фронтенда. решение @smackmychi мне подходит, большое всем спасибо

Comment: @zidim, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

```
update A set sum = sum + (<число>/100*percent) where filter=1;
```